# How to prohibit modifying an object property with a getter

Tags: javascript

If I don't allow writing to an object property is it enough to define only a getter like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(fileNavigator, "isRoot", {
    get: function () {
        return this.currentPath.length === 0;
    }.bind(this)
});

var r = fileNavigator.isRoot;
```

// works OK

```
fileNavigator.isRoot = 4;
```

// throws

```
TypeError: Cannot set property isRoot of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

Which is expected. I'm wondering whether this is how it should be done?

Comment: Yes, if you want a non-writable property, it is expected that assignment throws - and that's how it is done, yes.

Comment: @Shadow: this has nothing to do with ES6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the property to be recomputed each time you get it, which is your case, then yes, what you did is just fine, except for the `.bind(this)` which is unnecessary **and wrong** (thank you @torazaburo). If you absolutely want to bind the function, you need to use `.bind(fileNavigator)`, or else the value of `this` is almost certainly not going to be `fileNavigator`, as intended.

If you want the property to be a readable *constant*, you don't need the getter function since it would not have to compute anything. Instead you use the other kind of property descriptor:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'propertyName', {
    value: 'myValue',
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false
});
```

Comment: *the other kind of property descriptor* is called a **data descriptor**. By the way, `bind(this)` is not just unnecessary, I'm pretty sure it is wrong and will cause the code to fail.

Comment: @torazaburo Not sure where you got this "data descriptor" naming... http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-descriptor-specification-type Also, you're right about the `.bind(this)`, I hadn't seen that, thanks.

Comment: Look a bit further down: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isdatadescriptor

Comment: @FelixKling One could argue that those are function names, shortened for convenience, and that the type name is and remains "Property Descriptor", but at this point it would be nitpicking in vain. Whatever name is accurate and understood by all is fine. I just got used to "property descriptor" (with "property") from the MDN.

Comment: Well, of course they are property descriptors. But since there are two different kinds it makes sense to be able to name them. And fwiw, MDN also mentions those names: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty . So yeah, those names are accurate and understood :)